# Get the maximum N elements (along with their indices) of an Array

Tags: arrays, scala

I've got an array that contains `Integers` as the one shown below:

```
val my_array = Array(10, 20, 6, 31, 0, 2, -2)
```

I need to get the maximum 3 elements of this array along with their corresponding indices (either using a single function or two separate funcs).

For example, the output might be something like:

```
// max values
Array(31, 20, 10)

// max indices
Array(3, 1, 0)
```

Although the operations look simple, I was not able to find any relevant functions around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way - `zipWithIndex` followed by sorting:

```
val (values, indices) = my_array
  .zipWithIndex       // add indices 
  .sortBy(t => -t._1) // sort by values (descending)
  .take(3)            // take first 3
  .unzip              // "unzip" the array-of-tuples into tuple-of-arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
(my_array zip Stream.from(0)).
  sortWith(_._1 > _._1).
  take(3)

res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((31,3), (20,1), (10,0))
```